# Determine if $\frac{f(z_1) - f(z_2)}{(z_1 - z_2)^2}$ is entire.

Tags: complex-analysis, multivariable-calculus

Let $f$ be a given entire function.
Let $z_1,z_2$ be complex variables.

I know  $\frac{f(z_1) - f(z_2)}{z_1 - z_2}$ is entire.
If $ f $ is a polynomial we can simplify it. So then we have factorization.

But can we Determine if $\frac{f(z_1) - f(z_2)}{(z_1 - z_2)^2}$ is entire ?

Do we use algebra or calculus for that ?

Edit :

There seems to be Some confusion about what it means to be entire for two complex variables.
It simply means analytic in both variables for any pair $(z_1,z_2)$.

For instance $f(z_1,z_2) = \frac{z_1^2 - z_2^2}{z_1 - z_2} = z_1 + z_2$ is analytic.
But $\frac{f(z_1,z_2)}{z_1 - z_2} = \frac{z_1^2 - z_2^2}{(z_1 - z_2)^2} = \frac{z_1 + z_2}{z_1 - z_2} $ has a (nonremovable ) pole at ${z_1 - z_2} $ and thus not analytic everywhere hence not entire.

Note $f$ is defined as entire , not neccessarily a polynomial.
I just gave examples with polynomials because that is easiest.

Comment: An entire function is, technically, a function of one complex variable.

Comment: What do you mean you know $(f(z_1)-f(z_2))/(z_1-z_2)$ is entire?

Comment: Since $f$ is entire it has a power-series $f = \sum a_n (z-z_2)^n$ about $z_2$. Use this to derive the power-series of $g(z) = \frac{f(z) - f(z_2)}{(z-z_2)^2}$. This will have a pole unless some critera are satisfied which will give you your answer.

Comment: @ Winter , seems intresting. But it got me confused.

Comment: @Winther You seem to be addressing a different question. I would still like to know what the OP means by "$(f(z_1)-f(z_2))/(z_1-z_2)$" is entire. There are two variables there.

Comment: I edited. Everything should be clear now.Btw I cant login properly. Hope this is not my last activity. Im using recovery account now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In particular, you want 
$$
z \mapsto \frac{f(z)-f(z_2)}{(z-z_2)^2}
$$
to be entire for every fixed $z_2$. But since (locally)
$$
f(z)-f(z_2) = f'(z_2)(z-z_2) + \frac12 f''(z_2)(z-z_2)^2 + \cdots
$$
this only happens when $f'(z_2) = 0$. (Otherwise the one-variable function above has a pole at $z=z_2$.) But $z_2$ was arbitrary, so in fact $f'(z) = 0$ for all $z$, i.e. $f$ must be constant.

Conversely, it's obvious that constant functions are solutions.

Comment: I assume this is what Whinter was aiming at. Seems correct. +1.